# Unexpected output while converting RGB image to LAB image

Tags: python, opencv, color-space, scikit-image

I am trying to extract the LAB a-channel of a 32-bit RGB image. However I fail to read the image correctly and I get unexpected results.

```
import cv2
org = cv2.imread('42.png', -1)
print org.dtype
# print uint8
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(org, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
l,a,b = cv2.split(lab_image)
cv2.imshow('', a)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Original image:
http://labtools.ipk-gatersleben.de/images/42.png

Expected output (ImageJ):
http://labtools.ipk-gatersleben.de/images/imagej_out.png

OpenCV output:
http://labtools.ipk-gatersleben.de/images/python_out.png

I also tried to read/convert the image with skimage but the result is the same...

Comment: Try using `cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB`, since OpenCV reads BGR, not RGB. You probably need also to be sure to load in BGR using `cv2.imread('42.png', cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)`. In any case, use `cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED` instead of `-1` which is quite criptic

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I tried them but unfortunately the result is the same...

Comment: From where you derived the expected output? It doesn't seems to be correct

Comment: From ImageJ (convert to LAB space).

Comment: @snowflake I also agree with ZdaR. You must be mistaking something for something else. Please check and come back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code has several issues. First, as Miki correctly pointed out, you have to swap the red and blue channels. According to [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#cvtcolor) (emphasis mine):

> Note that the default color format in OpenCV is often referred to as RGB but **it is actually BGR** (the bytes are reversed)

Then you need to cast the image to `float32` (because `float64` is not supported by `cv2.cvtColor`) and scale it down to fit the 0..1 range:

> In case of linear transformations, the range does not matter. But in case of a non-linear transformation, an input RGB image should be normalized to the proper value range to get the correct results, for example, for RGB → Lu<sup>***</sup>v<sup>***</sup> transformation. For example, if you have a 32-bit floating-point image directly converted from an 8-bit image without any scaling, then it will have the 0..255 value range **instead of 0..1 assumed by the function**. So, before calling `cvtColor`, **you need first to scale the image down**

The values of `a` returned by `cv2.cvtColor` are constrained to be [image: -127 <= a <= 127]. For improved visualization it is useful to stretch contrast by subtracting `a.min()` from `a` and rescale the resulting values by a factor `255./(a.max() - a.min())` to fit the range 0..255. If you do so, you should obtain the expected result. Here's the the full code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
org = np.float32(cv2.imread('42.png', -1))/255.
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(org, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
l, a, b = cv2.split(lab_image)
a_scaled = np.uint8(255.*(a - a.min())/(a.max() - a.min()))
cv2.imshow('', a_scaled)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

#### Bonus

You can obtain the same<sup>†</sup> result with scikit-image:

```
from skimage import io, color
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

org = io.imread('http://labtools.ipk-gatersleben.de/images/42.png')
lab_image = color.rgb2lab(org)
a = lab_image[:, :, 1]

fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
plt.set_cmap('gray')
ax.imshow(a)
```

[image: a-channel]

† Actually the results yielded by OpenCV and scikit-image are not exactly equal. There are slight differences due to numeric errors associated to floating-point arithmetic. Such discrepancies stem from the fact that `cv2.cvtColor` returns three 2D arrays of **float32** whereas `skimage.color.rgb2lab` yields a 3D array of **float64**.

Comment: Normalizing to [0.0,1.0] is automatically done by `cv2.cvtColor` when the input type is `uint8`. Just normalizing the output gives the same picture as `ImageJ`. But I think it is a contrast-adjusted version, not the "LAB representation" of the original image.