# Why am I getting black image while writing LAB space images to a directory?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-conversion

I am trying to find the redness of skin disease called rosacea.

Here is the original image.

[image]
So I convert RGB image to LAB color space.

```
lab_image = cv2.cvtColor(x, cv2.COLOR_RGB2LAB)
```

Now on displaying it, I get the LAB colour of the image:

[image: lab image]

Now I want to save all this information as a jpeg file to a directory. so I use the following command.

```
cv2.imwrite('new.jpg',lab_image)
```

But I get a black image, like this:

[image: black image]

How can I save that LAB blue coloured information as a jpeg file in Python?

Comment: Could be related: [Unexpected output while converting RGB image to LAB image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586276/unexpected-output-while-converting-rgb-image-to-lab-image)

Comment: Try printing `lab_image[:,:,0].mean()` to see the mean Hue, then `lab_image[:,:,2].mean()` to see the mean Lightness in order to check the averages are in range 0..255.

Comment: the Mean hue is  4.8895955.
the Mean lightness is  -3.6559463.

Comment: @GeorgyThanks for the suggesting link but it did not help. The hard way would be to screenshot the lab converted images when viewing them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I want to save the lab image in the jpg format, so the jpg image (rpg) will show all the blue colour and everything. Is there a method for that.

Comment: Sorry, disregard my last comment - I was think of HSL rather than Lab. D'oh.

Comment: `lab_image[:,:,0].mean()` will be the mean Lightness, and `lab_image[:,:,1].mean()` will be the `a` channel. Basically, your images are not in the correct ranges (0..255) for a JPEG - the `a` and `b` channels are in the range -126..+128. Can you provide your original input image please?

Comment: Also, the image as displayed does not show all the information in the Lab image. Most variation is clipped. I suggest you do a contrast stretch before displaying, and display each channel separately rather than together as RGB.