# Transforming for LAB from a PIL Image (RGB2LAB) vs CV2 (BGR2LAB) give different values

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, png

I am reading a .png image, using both packages PIL and cv2.
If I do this

```
    #PIL 
    img = Image.open(path_img)  
    lab = np.uint8(color.rgb2lab(img))  

    # cv2
    img_cv2 = cv2.imread(path_img)  
    lab_cv2 = cv2.cvtColor(img_cv2, cv2.COLOR_BGR2LAB)
```

lab and lab_cv2 give really different values. What could be the reason?

specifically when I do this:

```
    print("img lab PIL", lab[:, :, 1])
    print("img lab cv2", lab_cv2[:, :, 1])
```

the results are:

`img lab PIL [[  3   2   2 ...   0   0   0]  [  3   1   1 ...   0   0   0]  [  2   2   2 ...   0   0   0]  ...  [  0   0   0 ...   1   0   0]  [  0 255 255 ...   0   0   0]  [  0   0   1 ...   1   1   0]] <br/>`

`img lab cv2 [[132 132 130 ... 130 130 128]  [132 132 132 ... 130 128 128]  [132 130 130 ... 130 128 130]  ...  [130 128 130 ... 129 129 128]  [128 128 128 ... 128 128 129]  [128 128 130 ... 129 129 128]]`

If I enter the following , the results in rgb/bgr are equivalent:

```
    print("r channel img PIL", np.uint8(img)[:, :, 0])
    print("r channel img cv2", img_cv2[:, :, 2])
```

`img lab PIL [[29 31 29 ...  2  1  0]  [29 28 30 ...  1  0  1]  [28 29 30 ...  2  2  1]  ...  [19 18 20 ... 57 51 53]  [14 18 17 ... 60 57 54]  [15 17 19 ... 58 57 49]] <br/>`
 `img lab cv2 [[29 31 29 ...  2  1  0]  [29 28 30 ...  1  0  1]  [28 29 30 ...  2  2  1]  ...  [19 18 20 ... 57 51 53]  [14 18 17 ... 60 57 54]`

So, I understand the error comes with the conversion to LAB.

Comment: I found the reason here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40586276/unexpected-output-while-converting-rgb-image-to-lab-image, to have the LAB conversion equal we have to read the cv2 img like this: img_cv2 = np.float32(cv2.imread(path_img, -1))/255.